# Product Variation Combinations

Tags: woocommerce

We have a site that's selling products with multiple color options: Base Color and Accent Color.  When a base color is selected, the accent color is filtered based on the variation combinations that are available.  Also, when an accent color is selected the base color is filtered in the same way. This creates an issue that if someone wants to select a new base color that isn't necessarily available with the currently selected accent color, they're stuck.  Is there a way to always display all Base colors (1st attribute) and only filter the 2nd attribute based on the 1st and a 3rd based on the 2nd.

[product link](https://tallpen.newlorvete.com/product/tall-pen/)

Comment: So you are going to need a very **custom** kind of multistep variation selector tool/plugin (with a lot of javascript/jQuery in it), and the result will also depend of your product variations settings for each product. This is a complicated development. Try to search around existing multistep product selector tools/plugins . Also if you are already using some additional plugins actually, is useful to mention that in your question…

Comment: I was using swatches, but that still has the same issue since its part of woocommerce.

Comment: *(You should update your question with that interesting detail)* — There is many possible ways to do things and a lot of different plugins (and combination of plugins) to achieve advanced customizations… But most of them will need in case like yours, additional advanced coding to get them work. This is a real development subject, and not a small customization. In WooCommerce everything is possible depending first on choices (plugin, settings and ways to do things), time, coding skills and knowledge…

Comment: Agree with Loic that this sounds like custom development, either for yourself or for a hired developer. You might be able to get something sort of similar with [WooCommerce Composite Products](https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/)